# How to hide ONLY one file on Desktop?

Tags: 16.04, files

I work in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I have Unreal Engine installed. As you know, UE is only for MacOS and Windows, so I had to use the source code from Github. I installed it, but if I move the UE folder from Desktop to Downloads and try to run the shortcut, it says that it couldn't(even if I modify the UE's folder's location from Properties). Because I hate putting too much shortcuts/files on Desktop, I want to hide the file for UE. Do you think if I hide the folder,the shortcut will work? If yes, can you tell me how to hide it?

The UE's folder is on the Desktop. If I move it anywhere on the PC and change the path in the shortcut:

[image]

OR

[image]

So, what should I do?

P.S. : This [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-urPcMjgvDxJhlmnpFbMD_WOdbwh1bNf) shows you how does the UE responds to the modify.

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: You can hide files and folders by adding a dot, ".", to the beginning of the name. For example, if the name is EU, then .EU will be hidden.

Comment: Put a dot at the beginning of the folder on desktop, then change the location in properties, see if it works.

Comment: @mikewhatever Renaming a file/folder to include a leading . (dot) character will make that folder unaccessible  by the application that uses it.

Comment: @Ravexina Renaming a file/folder to include a leading . (dot) character will make that folder unaccessible by the application that uses it.

Comment: So, as I can understand, if I hide the UE's folder,  the shortcut won't open UE because it can't see the folder. Do you think that if I move the folder to usr/share or /opt and then modify the path to the folder in shortcut's properties will work? If no, do you have another idea to make this issue working?

Comment: @heynnema not if you change its path in the application, right?

Comment: What do you mean? To modify from the setup.sh?

Comment: @Ravexina **IF** you have access to the source code for the application, and **IF** you're able to locate all references to the UE folder, etc.

Comment: @Matthew please see my updated answer. If it works for you, it would be the easiest solution.

Comment: @heynnema read my first comment again, I didn't say (just rename the directory) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a text file called `.hidden` at the top level of your home directly. In this text file, add the name of the file/folder to hide. Log out, log in, and that file/folder will no longer be displayed.

**Update: #1** As was pointed out, the `.hidden` file that you create may need to be placed in the directory where the file that you wish to hide is, so in your case, in `~/Desktop`.

In `terminal`...

`pico ~/Desktop/.hidden` # to create/edit the file

UnrealEngine

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save your edits

hit <kbd>Return</kbd> key to confirm filename to save to

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

log out

log in

Comment: Don't you mean in "*Create a text file called* `.hidden` *in* `~/Desktop/`" instead of "*at the top level of your home*"? OP wants to hide a file located at Desktop. I don't think putting `Desktop/filename` in `~/.hidden` will work.

Comment: @pomsky you may be right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Please read the question again...

Comment: @Matthew I reread the question. I made a slight edit to my update. Is there something specific that you'd like to point out that maybe I'm missing?

Comment: Do you think the shortcut will see the folder?

Comment: @Matthew are you asking about the "UnrealEngine Editor" icon that's on your Desktop? Using the `.hidden` method won't change how that works. The UE folder will just not be visible in Nautilus.

Comment: No. I'm asking about the folder with UE's source code.

Comment: @Matthew you're going to have to clarify what the path to UE's source code folder is. What shortcut? I thought that your problem was with the UnrealEngine folder on your desktop. You've lost me.

Comment: So I have a shortcut and the folder of UE. I want to move the folder from  Desktop, because I don't want to have too much things on it. If I move the UE's  folder from Desktop anywhere on the PC and change the path to the folder from the shortcut, it displays 2 error messages that are displayed in the question. The question is "How to move UE's folder to  make it working?".

Comment: @Matthew Leaving the shortcut, and the UnrealEngine folder, in their normal places on the Desktop, go ahead and follow the instructions that I put into Update #1 in my answer. When you log back in the UnrealEngine folder should be hidden. Report back.

Comment: Can you make a video to show me exactly? Sorry for my bad knowledge...because I write pico ~/Desktop/.hidden then write"UnrealEngine", then I press control-o and then I have other commands excluding control-x...

Comment: @Matthew after control-o you have to hit the return key to confirm the filename to save to.

Comment: Yeah I press control-c (return), then control-x. It asks if i want to save the changes and I press Y. It returns me at the main menu.

Comment: Not control-c. Please read the updated instructions carefully. control-o, return, control-x.